# Send notification once in a week

Tags: android, timer, notifications, alarm

I want to notify the user about answer the weekly questions.I need to send the notification to the user even my app is not running.The notification will send once in a week. 
When user clicks the notification my app will gets open.
I tried this via Timer and TimerTask().This notifies the user when my app is running.How can I send the notification to the user while app is not running.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Try to use AlarmManager!

Comment: Have you look into notification API as Urban Air Ship ?

Comment: How can i relate AlarmManager with Notification class

Comment: You need to use `AlarmManager` and mehod `setRepeating()` with timei nterval `AlarmManger.DAY * 7`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code uses Alarmmanager with BroadcastReceiver which will help you out achieving your need.

In your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(am.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeInMillis(), am.INTERVAL_DAY*7, pendingIntent);
```

System.currentTimeInMillis() - denotes that the alarm will trigger at current time, you can pass a constant time of a day in milliseconds.

Then create a Receiver class something like this,

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    public void showNotification(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reqCode, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Some text");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(reqCode, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Also you have to register your BroadcastReceiver class in your manifest file, like the following.
In your AndroidManifest.xml file, inside  tag,

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.receivers.Receiver"></receiver>
```

Here "com.example.receivers.Receiver" is my package and my receiver name.

Comment: May I know what is that REQUEST_CODE+2 in pending Intent?

Comment: REQUEST_CODE is some integer value that makes the pending intent unique. I have initialized a value for that.

Comment: I put 0 for place.Why do you add 2 to that value?Is INTERVAL_DAY has any value.For checking i need to replace that value?

Comment: I've edited it for your convenience, just pass any value in place of REQUEST_CODE. And INTERVAL_DAY is inbuilt in android, it has the milliseconds value for one day. For one week I multiplied it with 7. You don't have to alter its value.

Comment: Yeah sure, for checking you can alter INTERVAL_DAY to some small value. For example if you replace it with 30 * 1000, the alarm will trigger every 30 seconds.

Comment: I guess you haven't included your receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml file, I've edited the answer, please take a look at that.

Comment: The above code is sending notification on App launch too :(. Please help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, isn't it supposed to be System.currentTimeMillis() instead of System.currentTimeInMillis() ?

Comment: What if its once a day at 12 pm?