# Push notification if app has not open for a week when the app is not running (Android)

Tags: android, notifications

I am writing code to push notification for my app, but I do not know how to show this notification. The notification will be showed when users have not use my app for a week, and even the app is not running, the app still can send the notification. Please help me. Thank you.
This is my code to send a notification.

```
private void showNotification(){
    final NotificationManager mgr=
            (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //Notice message
    Notification note=new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            "Notification is coming!",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    // This pending intent will open class after notification click
    PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class),
            0);

    //After swipe down notification
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Title",
            "Context", i);

    //After uncomment this line you will see number of notification arrived
    //note.number=2;
    mgr.notify(notificationID, note);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Send notification once in a week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262711/send-notification-once-in-a-week) you just need to save when the app is opened, and then schedule a notification 7 days in future, this each time the user open the app.

You can also save each alarm with an unique identifier so you can later disable it.

Something like:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, _id, intent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Or to cancel it:

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

`_id` is the key to cancel the active alarm.

Remember when using `AlarmManager` all the Alarms disappear when the device is rebooted.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!