# How set a notification every Saturday?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to notify the user every Saturday reminding an event.
I am using Android Studio.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: > Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262711/send-notification-once-in-a-week

Comment: I tried that already but it doesn't specify the notification will appear on saturday

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is

Import this in your java file `import java.util.Calendar;`
 and copy this in whichever function you'll use.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
if(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY){
            text1.setText("True");//this is optional just to show that this is working perfectly.
//You can do whatever in this, it will only works when the day is saturday.
        }
```

Comment: You can find how to notify or show notification by yourself. This is enough for what you want.

Comment: will this send the notification even if the app is not running? thanks

Comment: This is not for notification. This is to find out whether it's a saturday or not. For notification find, find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262711/send-notification-once-in-a-week).

Comment: And for sending notifications when app is not running, use notification services.